# Avoid repeating data in columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables, all of them are linked with PK and FK. The tables are acc_details , acc_info , acc_bill

```
TABLE : acc_info

ID     |    acc_no         |  rate
______________________________________
1      |         00001     |     0
2      |         00002     |     21
3      |         00003     |     21
4      |         00004     |     21 

TABLE : acc_details

id_dls |    acc_type       |  address         |  **ID**
________________________________________________________
1      |        store      |     pekan        |  1
2      |     water plant   |     raub         |  1
3      |       store       |     kuantan      |  2
4      |      pump house   |     temerloh     |  2


TABLE : acc_bill

id_bill |        acc_no    |  charge_1        |  charge_2
________________________________________________________
1       |       00001      |     20.00        |  12.00
2       |       00002      |     15.00        |  16.00
```

PK ---> ID , acc_no FROM acc_info
FK ---> ID FROM acc_details , acc_no FROM acc_bill

i was hoping the outcome to be like this

```
address     |    acc_type       |    acc_no       |     charge_1  | charge_2
_________________________________________________________________________________
pekan       |    store          |    00001        |      20.00    |   12.00
raub        |    water plant    |                 |               |   
kuantan     |    store          |    00002        |      15.00    |   26.00
temerloh    |    pump house     |                 |               |
```

But then from the result of my query, the acc_no / charge_1 / charge_2 are repeated aswell  thus causing problems when i SUM(charge_1)

How can this be solve?

**UPDATE**

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT address , acc_type , acc_bill.acc_no , charge_1 , charge_2 
                        FROM   acc_info , acc_details , acc_bill
                        WHERE  acc_info.id = acc_details.id 
                        AND acc_info.acc_no = acc_bill.acc_no 
                        AND month ='".$month."' 
                        AND acc_category= 'Telekom Malaysia'" ); 

$result1 = mysql_query
("SELECT SUM(charge_1) AS Total_1 , 
         SUM(charge_2) AS Total_2
FROM   acc_info , acc_details , acc_bill
                        WHERE  acc_info.id = acc_details.id 
                        AND acc_info.acc_no = acc_bill.acc_no 
                        AND month ='".$month."' 
                        AND acc_category= 'Telekom Malaysia'" );
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to show your actual request.

Comment: `mysql`? Show us your work so far also.

Comment: This is the way SQL works.  You've not given the SQL any way to know to put the costs on which line.  You could accomplish this if we can say that costs should only be assiged to acc_Type of store however.

Comment: Is this mySQl, SQL Server or something else?

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED: but perhaps this...

```
SELECT address, acc_Type, acc_no charge_1, charge_2
FROM acc_info AI
INNER JOIN acc_Details AD
 on AI.ID = AD.ID
LEFT JOIN acc_bill AB
 on AI.acc_no = AB.Acc_no
 AND AD.acc_Type = 'store'
ORDER BY AI.ID, AD.id_DLS
```

If, what you're after is all records from the first two tables, and only those records that match in the 3rd when records from the second table are of acc_Type store, then using a left join to the third table and only joining on type of store should do it.

I'm assuming store is a unique qualifier, if it's not and you're after just matching on ONE of the entries from the second table, and it doesn't matter which, this gets a little more complicated in that we have to get the min or max ID of that subset.

Comment: No, store aren't an unique qualifier, they are not going to get pick by user all the time, but the acc_no is, but the charge_1 and 2 keep repeating and adding more value